# How to change functions call order

Tags: jquery

I've got a list of images (`<img>`), that I iterate like in a code below

```
$('.img').each(function(key,value){

  (function(){

    $(value).fadeOut('slow');
    $(value).attr('src','images/new.png');
    $(value).fadeIn('slow');

  })()

})
```

And the question is - How could i change attribute and then call `fadeOut/fadeIn` function.
In this case - at first, attributes change and than both effects work.

Comment: You want to perform that in sequence?

Comment: I cannot specifically say why this is happening but you can use `callback` from `fadeOut` to make it work as expected.. `$(value).fadeOut('slow',function(){    $(value).attr('src','images/new.png').fadeIn('slow')});`

Comment: Yes, i want firstly fadeOut element -> change attribute -> fadeIn element. So it could be some animation logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) callback; `fadeOut` *starts* the fadeout process, but it continues and completes *asynchronously* (later). Also, there's no need for that inner function:

```
$('.img').each(function(key,value){
    var $value = $(value);
    $value.fadeOut('slow', function() {      // Note we're using
        $value.attr('src','images/new.png'); // the callback
        $value.fadeIn('slow');               // to run this
    });
});
```

Or:

```
$('.img').each(function(key,value){
    $(value).fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).attr('src','images/new.png')
               .fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

---

If that image (`images/new.png`) may not be in cache, it would be best to precache it. Otherwise, the `fadeIn` may start before the image is loaded. Waiting for the `load` event on the image can be problematic, particularly on an existing `img` element you're changing the `src` on. If you want to wait for `load`, I'd probably replace the `img` entirely, like this:

```
$('.img').each(function(key,value){
    $(value).fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $("<img class=img>")
            .on("load", function() { // Note hooking load BEFORE setting src
                $(this).fadeIn('slow');
            })
            .attr("src", "images/new.png")
            .hide()
            .replaceAll(this);
    });
});
```

...but really simpler to just precache it.

Live example:

```js
$('.img').each(function(key, value) {
  $(value).fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $("<img class=img>")
      .on("load", function() { // Note hooking load BEFORE setting src
        $(this).fadeIn('slow');
      })
      .attr("src", "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/1c9adcda917a5646e8ebe93738d23a3f?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1")
      .hide()
      .replaceAll(this);
  });
});
```

```html
<img class="img" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ca3e484c121268e4c8302616b2395eb9?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the animation is executed **asynchronously**.

As someone mentioned in the comments you need to utilize the callback parameter from `fadeOut`:

```
$('.img').each(function(key, value) {
    $(value).fadeOut('slow', function() {
        // fadeOut animation completed
        $(value).attr('src','images/new.png')

        $(value).fadeIn('slow')
    })
})
```

Comment: Of course if you want to fadeIn when the image loaded, you need another callback.

Answer (score 1):

You could use javascript `.promise()` with jquery which you can use as `$.when()`

```
$('.img').each(function(key, value) {
    $.when($(value).fadeOut()).done(function() {
        $(value).attr('src', 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/1c9adcda917a5646e8ebe93738d23a3f?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1').fadeIn();
   })
});
```

```js
$('.img').each(function(key, value) {
  $.when($(value).fadeOut()).done(function() {
    $(value).attr('src', 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/1c9adcda917a5646e8ebe93738d23a3f?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1').fadeIn();
  })
});
```

```html
<img class="img" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/62c8139675bef978e1d92c816f052262?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```